# How to use LongPress in cocos2d-x

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x

I want whent I touchBegan sprite 1 , sprite 2 move . When touchEnd , sprite2 stopAction.

```
void GameScene:: ccTouchesBegan( cocos2d::CCSet * touches, cocos2d::CCEvent * event ){
    CCTouch *touch = (CCTouch *)touches->anyObject();
    CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();
    CCPoint convertedlocation = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
    if (turnUp->boundingBox().containsPoint(convertedlocation)) {
        this -> turnUpClick();
    }
    if (turnDown->boundingBox().containsPoint(convertedlocation)) {
        this -> turnDownClick();
    }
    if (turnLeft->boundingBox().containsPoint(convertedlocation)) {
        this -> turnLeftClick();
    }
    if (turnRight->boundingBox().containsPoint(convertedlocation)) {
        this -> turnRightClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are two things that can be done to improve your code (in terms of cocos2dx)

1. You (propably) don't need the multitouch version of this method, as there is nothing in this code to suggest that. Unless you will be actually using multitouch in the future. The single touch version is `ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)`.
2. You should consider using a `CCMenu`, as it will help you maintain your code if you have lots of buttons. Also, taking into consideration that you want to register two events (touch down and touch up) you may look into CCControlButton as well.

To the problem at hand :

Given your snippet of code, you should start your appropriate actions in the methods that you indicated you have, and then in `ccTouchEnded` you should call `sprite2->stopAllActions()` (of course, `sprite2` should be the real name of your variable).

Let me know if anything is unclear.